# autoit - how to submit the 3rd form on the current webpage

Tags: autoit

I had to edit my question because I felt I was not describing it correctly

I am trying to submit a form on a current webpage. The problem is that this form that I am trying to submit is coming from 2 previous submit forms. So I cant just call the url using `$oForms = _IEFormGetCollection ($oIE)` because the original URL of `$oIE` has changed.

I use on the first form submit this code which works fine, but once I get to the next page I have a new url and I need to submit that form as well. How can I call the current page and get the 3rd form on the page and submit that?

```
$oForms = _IEFormGetCollection ($oIE)
For $oForm In $oForms
  _IEFormSubmit($oForm)
Next
```

Comment: What does the error show?

Comment: `--> IE.au3 T3.0-1 Error from function _IEFormSubmit, $_IEStatus_COMError (-2147024891)` It seems to be targeting the 2nd form from what I can tell but I cant really confirm that.

Comment: Insert error handler and tell me what does it return.

Comment: Or, as Matt suggested, make sure you are searching for that form at the right time. Sometimes its not enough using IELoadWait. AJAX and dynamic page content can be a problem here.
Or maybe, these forms are in the Iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the page is changing, the original form collection becomes invalid when the new page is loaded. You need to get the new form collection each time.

The code would have to be something more like:

```
Local $aFormClassNames[3] = ["formClassNameOnPage1", "formClass2", "etcEtc"]

For $i = 1 To 3
    $oForm = _IEFormGetObjByName($oIE, $aFormClassNames[$i])

    Switch $i
        Case 1
            ; Fill out form 1
        Case 2
            ; Fill out form 2
        Case 3
            ; Fill out form 3
    EndSwitch

    _IEFormSubmit($oForm)
Next
```

It's better to use the form class name as well, rather than just blindly submitting forms by index. Web developers use tags in the strangest of places sometimes.

---

The above code and explanation is for the case when submitting a form leads to a new page with a new form.

For submitting the 3rd form on a single page, you can still use `_IEFormGetObjByName`. Most forms will have different names, but in the case that they have the same name, you can use the 3rd parameter of the function to specify a zero based index, for example:

```
$oForm = _IEFormGetObjByName($oIE, "theFormName", 2)
_IEFormSubmit($oForm)
```

Comment: but how do I only submit the 3rd form?

Comment: @CesarBielich, you said the URL was changing when you submitted forms, so how can you submit the third form without submitting the other two?

Comment: Sorry there are 3 separate forms on one page and I need to only submit the 3rd one.

Comment: @CesarBielich Then don't mark this answer as correct! I'll edit the answer with the solution to your actual question.